# Can I 'No Chill' in sanke kegs?

Tags: no-chill, sanke-keg

I'm trying to stop using plastic in my brewing and tought that it was a good idea to "No Chill" in sanke kegs (type "S" spear) instead of my old HDPE containers. But I dont' know if the valve will hold the negative pressure that the no chilling process create.

The valve will let the outside air come in? Or maybe the keg will knead to the inside with the vacuum? Please report your experience doing that or tell me ways to make it safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been doing this for years but with the spear removed and a 2" tri-clamp fitting. Fermenting a no-chill IPA now!
[image]

Comment: Cool! Sanke fermentors I've seen before. But at 'no chilling' time how you close it? Do you use that same TC with barbed hose fitting of the pic in the no chill moment? Thanks!

Comment: You use a 2" TC blank cap. For this keg you will need a gasket with a flat side. Available from typical brewing hardware suppliers.

Answer (score 3):

I've done this once with second runnings with a corny keg.  I filled the keg right after flame out, then placed into the cooler. Once chilled I transfered to carboy for fermentation. Had no negative effects on keg or beer. The pressure drop from contraction is so minimal the keg and valves are unaffected.

I guess if there was say 50% head space then the negative pressure might be enough to suck air in through valve. But that would be the worst of it. If concerned just put a sanitary air filter on the sanke valve.

Comment: Thanks, Evil. In corny I have tested it twice, 3 cornys each time. The first time I have air inside after chilled, the second time I bumped each one with CO2 sometimes and avoided it, but I don't think it was safe like the hdpe vessels that I can let in stock for days without any fear. I will wait for an answer about sanke specifically, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @jards yeah sounds like the pessure drop defeated the tension of the corny poppet springs.